# E-charts Needle Color

Tags: javascript, echarts

Anyone here can help me how to change the color of a needle in my speedometer chart? I copied this chart in Apache E-charts.

This is the script:

```js
    var dom = document.getElementById('performance-chart');
    var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
      renderer: 'canvas',
      useDirtyRect: false
    });
    var app = {};
    
    var option;

    option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'gauge',
      progress: {
        show: true,
        width: 18,
        itemStyle: {
          borderWidth: 10,
          color: '#8D7CDB'
        }
      },
      axisLine: {
        lineStyle: {
          width: 18
        }
      },
      axisTick: {
        show: false
      },
      splitLine: {
        length: 5,
        lineStyle: {
          width: 1,
          color: '#8D7CDB'
        }
      },
      axisLabel: {
        distance: 25,
        color: '#8D7CDB',
        fontSize: 9
      },
      anchor: {
        show: true,
        showAbove: true,
        size: 25,
        color: '#8D7CDB',
        itemStyle: {
          borderWidth: 8,
          borderColor: '#8D7CDB'
        }
      },
      title: {
        show: false
      },
      detail: {
        valueAnimation: true,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#8D7CDB',
        formatter: "{value}%",
        offsetCenter: [0, '70%']
      },
      data: [
        {
          value: 5.85
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

    if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
      myChart.setOption(option);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'needle' is represented by the [`pointer`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-gauge.pointer) parameter. Like most of echarts items, you can change the pointer style with [`itemStyle`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-gauge.pointer.itemStyle).

```js
series: [
{
  type: 'gauge',
  ... // the rest of the config
  pointer: {
    itemStyle: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  },
},
]
```